# why does this while loop print 32, it should break out before?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
x = 1
while ( x < 20 ):
 x = x * 2
print(x)
```

The x at the end is 32, should it not break out before? when it reaches 16?

Comment: Have you tried printing `x` inside the loop?

Comment: When it reaches 16, it's still less than 20. It prints 32 because 2 * 16 = 32 and 32 is greater than 20.

Comment: How is a "software developer" and "data scientist" with 22.2k reputation not able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You are doubling `x`, *then* checking if the result is less than 20. If you want the biggest result less than 20, you need to check the doubled value before assigning it to `x`. Something like

```
x = 1
while True:
    doubled = x * 2
    if doubled >= 20:
        break
    x = doubled

print(x)
```